# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'orjson.orjson'",

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to run a Python Lambda function (which ran successfully in 3.6, and I'm now trying to upgrade to a supported version). I'm getting this result:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'orjson.orjson'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

The orjson library is presumably a dependency of one of my dependencies, as I'm not importing it directly. I have tried to include all necessary dependencies as a layer, and I have experimented with a variety of ways to structure the zip file with the dependencies installed, but this issue persists.

Is there anything I might be overlooking when creating the zip file for the layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same issue, and found out today that it is because `orjson` is built on my Mac while AWS Lambda uses Amazon Linux, making the `orjson`'s cpython artifact incompatible when deployed.

Try using `--use-container` option when running `sam build`. This builds the artifact on an Amazon Linux container, and has resolved the issue for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if you run `pip install` on an `x86_64` machine but execute the python zip on a lambda with a `arm_64` runtime.  This is because `orjson` installs a binary that is architecture dependent.